# Which kind of magic fits a celtic-based setting?

Tags: system-agnostic, magic, druid, fantasy

I'm preparing a campaign set on mythic ireland-wales; and I would like to know which kind of spells, spellcasters, rituals and such could fit best to this scenario.

Spoken incantations? 
Brewed potions?
Magic wands and staffs?
Should I focus the tone on elementalism, animism, divine interventions, or astral rituals?

Who were the most likely to become magic users? 
How did one become a druid?
Who are the most likely to craft magic objects and how?

As a note, I am using advanced tech (primitive electricity, guns, trains) but the wilderness is still prevalent (lots of bogs, forests and rain). PCs are mostly human, though sometimes they may bear fairy heritage.

Comment: Ultimately this is too opinion based to meet our site criteria. A forum would be a better place for this type of constructive poll-seeking.

Comment: I don't think it's too opinion based, but it is way too broad.  "What of all kinds of Celtic fantasy stuff could fit into any RPG." If you narrowed it to something like "What heavily celtic-flavored magic systems exist for d20" or something you would get something more answerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much of the "Celtic" feel you're going for is dependent upon if you're thinking of pre-Christian paganism, or the cultural landscape after the conversion to Christianity. I will assume you mean the pre-Christian version, because that is more iconic. While the question is opinion based in many aspects, giving an overall description of Celtic culture may help in providing context for the type of mood and style you're trying to set.

**Elves and fairies are not your friends**
Like many old-world Pagan cultures, the aspects of Nature were revered as deities in old Celtic folklore. The most distinguishing characteristics of Celtic culture from a mythological standpoint, though, are its treatment of "the Fair Folk" (elves, pixies, etc.) These creatures were not the noble nature warriors you may envision from classical literature, but were rather raucous and often malicious pranksters who tormented mortals by devising clever traps or doing underhanded, sneaky things like stealing important items in the night. If your setting is to have these elements, remember to make them an obstacle, not a society to visit.

**Natural, primal magic is to be revered**
As Nature is the aspect that is revered, primal magic is a great fit- druids and shamans should feel right at home, flavor wise. Your more typical "arcane" casters can even be re-flavored in this light. A divination specialist is re-skinned to be a "Seer" who portends the future through mystic herbs. Potions and poultices instead of divine healing, that kind of thing.

**Magic users can be anyone, but they should all have a similar trait**
Magic users, in real-world historical context, derived from human's ability to put patterns together, regardless of whether those patterns were true or not. If a typical community found that a powerful seer had striking grey eyes, children born in that community with the same tint in their eyes were often expected to have the same gift. Again, those gifted in remembered herbal remedies and recipes for rituals were put in a position to be a "magic user".

**Artifacts are made by the hero, not the other way around**
As far as magic objects are concerned, in most folklore of Celtic tradition, magic weapons were magic not because they were crafted that way, but because of who held them. The skilled mythological warrior Cu-Culain didn't have a wizard craft him his spear Gae Bolg, the spear gained a mythic quality *because* it was his. Consider having weapons and items become imbued with magical power as characters become more powerful and/or do more awesome stuff with their equipment.

Comment: I love the idea of the heros making their own magical weapons. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that we just know so little about [druids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Druid). We know they were important to the people, possibly government officials, but they also had religious importance. It appears they believed in the immortality of souls, and that souls transfer from one body to another. This may or may not be different than other forms of reincarnation. Ancient sources talk about how druids performed their works orally, and that training to be a druid could take over 15, possibly up to 20, years. Ritual human sacrifice seemed to be limited to criminals. Ritual animal sacrifice was practiced, but not for the same reasons as human sacrifice. It also appeared that we have no record of female druids, but that may just be due to our lack of information.

How should this impact your choice of magic? Well, to go off of what little we know, your magic system should enforce or stress the following:

- Druids performed their functions without writing them down. Memorization is therefore imperative to a druid.
- Souls are immortal; druids should recognize this and act accordingly.
- They appeared to be intermediaries between gods and regular people.
- Sacrificing (of creatures) is important, either to bring justice or complete spells. (We're not sure why they performed those sacrifices, just that they did.)

If your druids do this, then they appear to be "accurate" to what we know of from history and archeological evidence. I would also suggest looking at more [Celtic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celtic_mythology), [Irish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_mythology), and [Welsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_mythology) Mythology for further ideas. These societies were less effected by the Romans/Christians, who effectively stamped out most of the information about the druids before anyone did an in-depth study of them. Sadly, the body of trustworthy literature on this subject is small, but it may be the best you can get.

< mini-rant > I wish we knew more about druids; it would make the folks at Wizards of the Coast and other game companies figure out what that class is actually supposed to do, and how it differs from their formulations of clerics/paladins/bards. To make things more complicated, there is some evidence that some druids were also bards, or that bards were an order of druids. < \mini-rant >

Comment: I'll try to get advantage of that lacking information to create something cool. Thank you for your answers, you really helped a lot.